# Entity Framework Core Lambda Expression join 4 tables and filter with where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have six tables as shown below. I am trying to get data based on `Application_name`, `Environment_name`, and `Status`.

**Status** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**Application** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**Servers** table:

```
Id, ServerName, Status
```

**Environments** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**ResourceGroup** table:

```
Id, Name, Application_Id, Environment_Id
```

**ServersResourceGroup:**

```
Id, Server_Id, Resource_Id
```

What I am trying to do is join all the require table and use where to filter data by `Application_name`, `Environment_name`, and `Status`

Here is my query I built, which returns all the data back by filtering `Application_name` but I am no way near to fulfill above requirement by adding additional filters by `Environment_name` and `Status` :(

So below is the query that returns all the data with `Application_name`

```
public IEnumerable<ResourceGroup> GetAllServersByApplication(string application_name, string environment_name, string status)
{
    var query = _context.ResourceGroup
            .Include(a => a.Application)
            .Include(t => t.Type)
            .Include(e => e.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(e => e.Environment)
            .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server)
            .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
            .Where(a => a.Application.Name == application_name)
            .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Here is the query that I am trying to write that will filter based on all three filters:

```
    public IEnumerable<ResourceGroup> GetAllServersByApplication(string application_name, string environment_name, string status)
    {
        var query = _context.ResourceGroup
            .Include(a => a.Application)
            .Include(t => t.Type)
            .Include(e => e.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(e => e.Environment)
            .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server)
            .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
            .Where(a => a.Application.Name == application_name)
            .Select(e => e.ServersGroup.Where(s => s.Environment.Name == environment_name && s.Server.Status.Name == status)
            .ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

I get a red line under `return query`. Please see below image:
[image]

Is there any easier way to write lambda query then what I am trying to do?

Any help is really appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Just a bit of advice: You don't need to use `Include()` on everything if you are not going to `Select` it. What I mean is if you don't need that data in your application then don't include it. The `Where` will work fine without the includes.

Comment: can you tell us what is the issue on your query ?

Comment: @Sampath - I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error is because you are now returning an collection of `ServersGroup` which is different than in your method signature. This is due to the fact that you added a Select clause and selected property `ServersGroup` from `ResourceGroup`. Filtering should happen in the `Where` clause. I updated the code below and moved your filter in the `Select` to the `Where`, also the included where was changed to an `Any` as a Where expects boolean clauses.

If it was your intention to only include certain `ServersGroup` within your `ResourceGroup` then you should filter those out in a join or outer join statement.

Also you probably do not need Include's everywhere. Includes are used for eager loading which ensures that only one roundtrip is necessary to the database to get the associated relationships. If you do not plan on accessing all these related properties then do not include them.

I do assume that your relationships are mapped correctly either in fluent mapping files or using attributes on the models.

```
public IEnumerable<ResourceGroup> GetAllServersByApplication(string application_name, string environment_name, string status)
{
    var query = _context.ResourceGroup
        .Include(a => a.Application)
        .Include(t => t.Type)
        .Include(e => e.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(e => e.Environment)
        .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server)
        .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
        .Where(a => a.Application.Name == application_name && a.ServersGroup.Any(s => s.Environment.Name == environment_name && s.Server.Status.Name == status))
        .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Comment: I do plan to access properties from include to access `Name` property from each table. I will try out join to see if I can add those properties to `ResourceGroup`. Thank you so much. Your query did help me understand what I was doing wrong with. :)